# Weird HTML 5 Canvas Antialiasing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, antialiasing

I've been playing with canvas element and discovered that when I attempt to draw NxN uniform solid-colored cells next to each other, in some width/height configurations, there are blurry white-ish lines between them.

For instance, this canvas is supposed to look black but contains some sort of *grid* which I conjecture to be a result of faulty antialiasing in the browser.

[image: The canvas demonstrating the issue.]

Suffice to say, this bug appears only in *some* configurations but I would like to get rid of it for good. Is there any way to circumvent this? Have you ever had problems with antialiasing in canvas?

I have made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngxjnywz/1/) which demonstrates the issue and allows you to play with the dimensions of the canvas and number of cells. It also contains the code I use to draw the cells, so that you can inspect it and tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCells; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfCells; ++j) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(j * cellWidth, i * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Petr.

Comment: Hello Petr, it would seem you forgot to provide your fiddle link, Could you please update

Comment: Just noticed it. Sorry, here you go! :)

Comment: A common trick is to transform the entire canvas by one pixel at the start to dodge this, I believe.

Comment: It does make sense, `300 / 70 = 4.285...` which will make any edge anti-alias, and because of that, a line will appear. It seems to do what is expected, because of rounding...

Comment: You can find a solution here [Filling the gaps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33788934/3877726)

Comment: @EvanKnowles I heard the same thing but with half pixel, is it possible that the translation offset somehow depends on the dimensions of the drawn object?

Comment: @somethinghere you are correct, but the lines are a consequence of precision loss due to the rounding and that is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through and trying several approaches, I've decided to come up with my own. I've created another (virtual) canvas which had integer dimensions corresponding to the number of cells in the grid.

After drawing all the cells in there, I call `context.drawImage()` on the main canvas and pass the virtual canvas as an argument along with offset and scale parameters to make it fit rest of my drawing. Assuming that the browser would scale the virtual canvas's image as a whole (and not as individual cells), I was hoping to get rid of the unwanted separator lines.

In spite of my efforts, the lines are still there. Any suggestions?

Here's the fiddle demonstrating my technique: https://jsfiddle.net/ngxjnywz/5/

Comment: I've discovered the culprit. Turns out this approach works as long as I don't shift the secondary canvas by 0.5 pixel (as suggested in the other answer). After removing `context.translate(0.5, 0.5)`, everything else fell into place.

Answer (score 4):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ngxjnywz/2/

snippet of javascript

```
var cellWidth = Math.ceil(canvasWidth / numberOfCells);
var cellHeight = Math.ceil(canvasHeight / numberOfCells);
```

Depending on the width, height and your numberOfCells you are sometimes getting a... lets say 4.2 which is 4, however this would be displayed wrong and will allow a 1 pixel blank line to appear. So all you need to do is use the `Math.ceil` function and this will cause your cellWidth and cellHeight to always be the higher number and you won't get blank lines anymore

Comment: Unfortunately rounding only works if lines are parallel to the X or Y axis, nor does it take into account any transformation that may be applied.

Comment: That is really nice and easy solution. It might get a bit messy since the cells will start overlapping and that might cause the order of drawing to suddenly become relevant, but since the same ceiled 'cellWidth' will be used to offset the drawing procedure, this will be prevented.

Comment: I have just tried "ctx.fillRect(j * cellWidth + 151, i * cellHeight + 77, cellWidth, cellHeight);" and it works without a problem however I can confirm that any "transform" on the grid will reproduce lines, however if you transform anything after the grid it is fine, Take a look at my link https://jsfiddle.net/ngxjnywz/4/

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to add a 0.5 pixel wide stroke around all the fills, using the same style as the fill and offsetting all drawing so that you render at the center of pixels rather than the top left.

If you add scaling or translation you will have to adjust the coordinates so that you still give the centers for your drawing coordinates.

In the end you can only reduce the artifacts but for many situations you will not be able to completely remove them.

This answer shows you how to remove the artifacts for an untransformed canvas.
[How to fill the gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33788934/3877726)

Comment: This is looking quite complex a procedure. In my particular setup, I would have to completely rethink the math of my grid drawing.

Comment: @PetrMánek True, but in other situations, this is indeed the simplest solution - just add .5 to all the coordinates.

Comment: @PetrMánek. The half-pixel trick works well at the cost of some redesign. Another workaround is to create "building blocks" on a second canvas and [assemble your design from those building blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355920/canvas-polygons-not-touching-properly)

Comment: Tried offsetting the drawing by 0.5px but the issue didn't go away. Although lines and texts in my canvas look much clearer now, the thin grid lines separating individual squares are still visible in some cases. And when I add 0.5px-wide stroke, everything starts to look bulky and messy.

Comment: You can try various stroke widths < 0.5 pixels. The alternative is to render to a canvas 2 or 4 times the size and then draw that canvas onto the original canvas with `ctx.drawImage(largeCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`  and `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled; = true;` that will reduce the artifacts further. Or use `ctx,getImageData()` and render the boxes your self, pixel by pixel. If its just boxes then there would not be that much involved.

Comment: I don't like the idea of guessing the stroke width, especially since my canvas adapts its dimensions to those of the window. On the other hand, the idea with the secondary canvas might just work. See the full answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34365436/1115613

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle and the fact is that you can not get a perfect result if `(canvas.width % numberOfCells)  !==  0` it is impossible to do as one or more cell boundaries will lay on a pixel and a pixel can not have two colours . You need to have it so that each cell is precisely lined up with pixel boundaries.